# Transposition map is positive definite but eigenvalues are not all positive

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider $n\times n$ matrices in $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ and consider the transposition map:
$$T: M_n(\mathbb{C}) \to M_n(\mathbb{C})\\A\mapsto A^T$$
This map is positive since it maps positive definite matrices to positive definite matrices.
On the other hand, the eigenvalues of $T$ are $\pm 1$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2117542/the-eigenvectors-of-the-transpose-operator))
, so they are not all positive.

Now, if $T$ were Hermitian/symmetric then this would contradict the fact that a Hermitian matrix is pos. def. iff all eigenvalues are positive.
So, am I correct to assume that this means that transposition is not Hermitian (or symmetric in the real case)? Probably, a stupid question but: To check if transposition is not symmetric, I want to take the tranpose. Is the transpose of $T$ simply the identity map?

Comment: In fact I haven't heard of "positive definite" matrices that aren't Hermitian (symmetric)...

Comment: When working over $\mathbb C$ being positive definite implies hermicity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's clear what taking the transpose of a linear map over $\Bbb C^n$ means, but it's not clear what the "transpose" of a map over $M_n(\Bbb C)$ should refer to.

To answer this question, consider the following definition of the "transpose" of a map over $\Bbb C^n$. Let $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ denote the usual "dot product" over $\Bbb C^n$, which is to say that $\langle x, y \rangle = x^\top y = \sum_i x_iy_i$. For a map $A$ over $\Bbb C^n$, the transpose of $A$ is the unique map $B$ such that for all $x,y \in \Bbb C^n$, we have
$$
\langle Ax,y \rangle = \langle x, By \rangle.
$$

With this as motivation, one answer to this question is as follows. Define the bilinear map $(\cdot,\cdot)$ over $M_n(\Bbb C)$ by
$
(A,B) = \operatorname{tr}(AB^\top) = \sum_{i,j} a_{ij}b_{ij}.
$
We can say that the "transpose" of $T$ is the unique map $S$ over $M_n(\Bbb C)$ for such that for all $A,B \in M_n(\Bbb C)$,
$$
(T(A),B) = (A,S(B))
$$
With this definition in mind, we note that if $T$ is the transpose map,
$$
(T(A),B) = \operatorname{tr}(A^\top B) = 
\operatorname{tr}[(A^\top B)^\top] = 
\operatorname{tr}(B^\top A) = \operatorname{tr}(AB^\top) = (A,T(B)).
$$
In other words, relative to this definition of the "transpose", the transpose map is "symmetric".

---

Along similar lines, if we transfer the definition of "positive definite" to this context, we find that $T$ fails to be positive definite even though it is a "positive" map in the sense you described. For a map $A$ over $\Bbb C^n$, if $A$ is positive definite, then every non-zero real vector $x \in \Bbb R^n$ should satisfy $\langle Ax,x \rangle > 0$.

Analogously, for a map $T$ over $\Bbb C^n$, if $T$ were "positive definite" by a reasonable definition, then it should hold that $(T(X),X) > 0$ holds for all non-zero $X \in M_n(\Bbb R)$. However, if we take $X$ to be a non-zero, real, skew-symmetric matrix, then it's easy to see that
$$
(T(X),X) = (-X,X) = -(X,X) < 0.
$$

Comment: This is really nice answer, thank you. But this leaves me confused, how it is possible that transposition can be positive definite and symmetric and still have negative eigenvalues?

Comment: Saying that $T$ is a "positive" map in this context is **not** the same as saying that it is "positive definite". Just as we had to redefine "transpose" for this context, we would also have to redefine "positive definite".

Comment: Thanks for the edit! super helpful again! I will accept the answer now. 
Do you happen to know if the following is true: A linear map over matrices is positive (mapping pos. def. matrices to pos. def. matrices) if all its eigenvalues are positive?

Comment: It is not true. As a counterexample, 
$$
\phi: \pmatrix{a&b\\c&d} \mapsto \pmatrix{a&2b\\3c&4d}
$$
has positive eigenvalues but is not a positive map.