# An endomorphism of the vector space $M_n(\mathbb R)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $f$ be the endomorphism defined by :
$$f\ :M_n(\mathbb R)→M_n(\mathbb R),\ M↦M^T$$
How can we show that $f$ is diagonalizable and its characteristic polynomial is :
$$\chi_f(X)=(X-1)^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}} (X+1)^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}$$

Comment: See [this post,](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2117542/81360) [this post,](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2297615/81360) and [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/638374/81360).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that $f^2 = \text{id}_{M_n(\Bbb{R})}$, which means the if you define the polynomial $p(x) = x^2 - 1$, then $p(f) = 0$. So, the minimal polynomial of $f$ divides $p(x)$.  i.e the minimal polynomial divides $(x-1)(x+1)$. Assuming $n>1$, it follows that the minimal polynomial can't be $x \pm 1$ (otherwise $f = \pm \text{id}_{M_n(\Bbb{R})}$). So, the minimal polynomial is $(x-1)(x+1)$. Since the minimal polynomial splits and all the roots have algebraic multiplicity $1$, it follows that $f$ is diagonalizable.

For the second part, use the fact that the minimal polynomial and characteristic polynomial have the same roots. From this, you know that $\chi_f(x) = (x-1)^{\alpha} (x+1)^{\beta}$ for some $\alpha, \beta$. Next, you also know that $\alpha + \beta = n^2$, the dimension of the space. Since you know $f$ is diagonalizable, we know that
\begin{align}
\alpha = \dim \ker(f- I) \quad \text{and} \quad \beta = \dim \ker(f+I)
\end{align}
So, let's try to compute this dimension. A matrix $A \in M_{n}(\Bbb{R})$ lies in $\ker(f-I)$ if and only if
\begin{align}
(f-I)(A) &= 0 \iff A^T = A
\end{align}
In other words, $\ker(f-I)$ is the set of symmetric matrices. This space has dimension $n(n+1)/2$ (the number of strictly upper-triangular entries plus the $n$ diagonal entries). Therefore, $\alpha = n(n+1)/2$. It follows that $\beta = n^2 - \alpha = n(n-1)2$. Hence.
\begin{align}
\chi_f(x) &= (x-1)^{\alpha} (x+1)^{\beta} = (x-1)^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}(x+1)^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}.
\end{align}

Comment: And for the second part of the question ??

Comment: @AchrafBOURASS I added the 2nd part.